# Docker zookeeper image unable to connect to sheepkiller/kafka-manager image

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper

I am using two images [sheepkiller/kafka-manager/](https://hub.docker.com/r/sheepkiller/kafka-manager/) (Tool from Yahoo Inc) but the image was made by someone with a weird sense of humor but it has good reviews.

And [zookeeper](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/zookeeper/)

I start ZooKeeper

```
docker run --it --restart always -d zookeeper
```

then try to start apache manager

```
docker run -it --rm  -p 9000:9000 -e ZK_HOSTS="your-zk.domain:2181" -e APPLICATION_SECRET=letmein sheepkiller/kafka-manager
```

Document says:

> (if you don't define ZK_HOSTS, default value has been set to "localhost:2181")

Error:

> Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=60000 watcher=org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@7bf272d3
>   [info] o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
>   [info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - zk=localhost:2181
>   [info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - baseZkPath=/kafka-manager
>   [warn] o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

I am using `Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6` on windows 10. I have tried several different things but was unsuccessful. I am assuming there is an issue with the ports, I [zookeeper config file](https://github.com/31z4/zookeeper-docker/blob/d5d320f94212691bd6e60326e45c152ac6784210/3.3.6/Dockerfile) and [/sheepkiller/kafka-manager/dockerfile/](https://hub.docker.com/r/sheepkiller/kafka-manager/~/dockerfile/) but I am not sure how to change these images after I already pulled them if that really is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work fine:

```
docker network create zookeeper-net
docker run -it --restart always -p 2181:2181 --network zookeeper-net --name zookeeper -d zookeeper
docker run -it --rm  -p 9000:9000 -e ZK_HOSTS="zookeeper:2181" -e APPLICATION_SECRET=letmein sheepkiller/kafka-manager
```

**Update**:

There is also a [compose file](https://github.com/sheepkiller/kafka-manager-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) to setup everything. I suggest you use that.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Error `Background exception was not retry-able or retry gave up` and `org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss` thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @Drew1208 Updated answer you can use the Docker compose file provided by the developer for the kafka image. That should work flawlessly.

Comment: `PS C:\Users\me\Documents\yahoo-monitoring> docker-compose up
ERROR:
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml`

I made a directory then a yml file and edited it with the correct settings, no avail.

Comment: @Drew1208 You need to copy/download this file https://github.com/sheepkiller/kafka-manager-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml and name it docker-compose.yml, then in same directiry run `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Now I am getting this `Yikes! Ask timed out on [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://kafka-manager-system/), Path(/user/kafka-manager)]] after [5000 ms]` when I make a cluster. Man been at this for 2 days. https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager/issues/401 I tried this but nothing.